# Google Apps Script Race Conditions Handling

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a spreadsheet that multiple people have access to edit. As part of the spreadsheet, I have a script that copies some data from one sheet to another when a checkbox on that row is set to true to begin an internal tracking process.

```
function onEdit(e){
  //get the sheet where the edit occurs
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();  
  var sourceRange = e.range;
  var sourceRow = sourceRange.getRow();
  var sourceColumn = sourceRange.getColumn();

  if((sourceSheet.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource") && 
  e.range.columnStart==18 && e.range.rowStart >= 2){
    if(e.value == "TRUE"){
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ScriptTestingTarget");

      var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRow,1,1,11).getValues();
      //splice off unneeded values
      sourceValues[0].splice(7,1)
      sourceValues[0].splice(3,2)
      sourceValues[0].splice(0,1)
    
      //insert new row on on target sheet
      var targetRows = targetSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()
      targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRows,1);
      targetSheet.getRange(targetRows+1,1,1,7).setValues(sourceValues)
    }
  }
}
```

Now this works really well for me at doing exactly that single task of copying a necessary data from a row, trimming off the rest, and inserting it into a new row on a different sheet. However, I'm trying to expand the functionality, and solve some issues with use-cases, such as if someone marks multiple rows as true quickly. When this happens, it will create a new row (sometimes multiple) on the target sheet, but then it will just overwrite the first new row with the copied data repeatedly.

I was thinking that perhaps instead of having the work done within the onEdit function, it would instead simply push the "work order" to an array that would function as a queue that would pop the work orders off the array upon completion. Hopefully this would allow more work to be added to the queue, as it works.

```
var workQueue = [];
var working = false;

function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();  
  var sourceRange = e.range;
  var sourceRow = sourceRange.getRow();
  var sourceColumn = sourceRange.getColumn();
  if((sourceSheet.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource") && 
  e.range.columnStart==18 && e.range.rowStart >= 2){
    if(e.value == "TRUE"){
      workQueue.push([0,sourceSheet,sourceRange,sourceRow,sourceColumn])
      if(workQueue.length<1 && working==false){
        doWork();
      }
    }
  }
}
function doWork(){
  working=true;
  while(workQueue.length>0){
    workOrder = workQueue[0]
    switch(workOrder[0]){
      //0: copy data for carrier tracking to sheet
      case 0:
        //copy data to sheet order
        var sourceSheet = workOrder[1];
        var sourceRange = workOrder[2];
        var sourceRow = workOrder[3];
        var sourceColumn = workOrder[4];
      

        //get values from sheet
        var sourceValues = sourceSheet(sourceRow,1,1,11);
        //trim and clean data
        sourceValues[0].splice(7,1);
        sourceValues[0].splice(3,2);
        sourceValues[0].splice(0,1);

        //insert new row in target sheet
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ScriptTestingTarget");
        var targetRows = targetSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
        targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRows,1);
        targetSheet.getRange(targeRows+1,1,1,7).setValues(sourceValues);
        workQueue.pop();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  working=false;
}
```

Something like this? though the example above doesn't actually work. The switch-case block is to add modularity as I add new functionality to the script, such as removing a row from the sheet. E.g.: someone set the value to true accidentally so they set it back to false, rather than going and deleting the row manually, I want to delete the row using an identifying Key-value. This would be added to the queue to be done in sequence forcing a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is onEdit won't even trigger, during simultaneous edits or quick edits. The only thing that may work is inside onEdit, you check all the rows of the sheet needed and do the necessary. A better way to do this is to not depend on the trigger onEdit, but use a menu function or a button.

Comment: The current version does work when there are multiple consecutive edits, but it doesn't work as intended. It will create a new row on the target sheet and then set the values on that row repeatedly, overwriting the old values. This spreadsheet has multiple sheets with thousands of populated cells each, so processing overhead is a concern.

Comment: @SciChronic Try `LockService`

Answer (score 0):

This might run a bit quicker:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "ScriptTestingSource" && e.range.columnStart == 18 && e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("ScriptTestingTarget");
    const [,b,c,,,f,,h,i,j,k] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getValues().flat();
    let vs = [b,c,f,h,i,j,k];
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 7).setValues([vs])
  }
}
```

But onEdit is not a particularly fast operation.  If you have a lot of simultaneous users you will probably not be able to use it.

Comment: Yeah, we're working with a spreadsheet with dozens of sheets (most are archival) with thousands of populated rows, so i'm looking for a robust solution.

Comment: This code definitely made it faster, but not by enough. When I applied this to our actual sheet, I still run into the issue that if I mark multiple rows to "TRUE" it will add some number of rows, then it will start writing all the copied information to the same row, overwriting what it had just copied.

Comment: Some have tried the use of LockService but I never have used it.  I would guess that it will make the problem even worse or frustrate your users or perhaps even both.  But you might like to investigate it.